# How do I get my threads to utilize 100% CPU?

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-usage

I have a simple Producer (1) and consumer (varying from 1-50) problem where the Producer simply adds elements in a Queue and the consumers read it. I am trying to get 100% CPU utilization.

Currently I am getting 20% utilization. And I cannot get 100% CPU utilization. I want all my CPU used to perform the operation faster. What should I look at?

Machine : i7 (4th generation - quad code with Hyper Threading) running windows 8 and Java 7.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
/*
 * Purpose is to test system clock granularity
 */

public class ClockGranularity{
        private static final int MaxExecutionTimeMsec = 6;
        //60*1000 milliseconds
        private static float delta = 0.01f;
        //Inter-arrival Time(IAT): in milliseconds
        static final int ArraySize =(int) ((float)MaxExecutionTimeMsec/delta);
        private static final int convertMilliToNano = 1000000;

        private static String getTime() {
                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                return format.format(cal.getTime());
        }
        /*
         * Invoke 1 producer vs 1,2,3 consumers
         * Write consumer to file
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                ClockGranularity.delta = delta*convertMilliToNano;
                long execStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long experimentStartTime = System.nanoTime();
                long execDuration, experimentRuntime;
                Buffer requestQueue = new Buffer();
                Producer producer = new Producer(requestQueue);
                Consumer consumer = new Consumer(requestQueue);
                Consumer consumer2 = new Consumer(requestQueue);
                Consumer consumer3 = new Consumer(requestQueue);
                consumer.start();
                consumer2.start();
                consumer3.start();
                do {
                        execDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - execStartTime;
                        experimentRuntime = System.nanoTime() - experimentStartTime;
                        if(experimentRuntime >= delta) {
                                experimentStartTime = System.nanoTime();
                        producer.run();
                        }
                } while (execDuration <= MaxExecutionTimeMsec);
                consumer.interrupt();
                consumer2.interrupt();
                consumer3.interrupt();
                delta/=convertMilliToNano;
                try {
                        String producerFile = "Producer-" + delta + " msec @" + getTime();
                        printToFile(producerFile,requestQueue.getQueue());
                        String consumerFile = "Consumer-" + delta + " msec@" + getTime();
                        printToFile(consumerFile, consumer.getValidateConsumerArray());
                        consumerFile = "Consumer2-" + delta + " msec@" + getTime();
                        printToFile(consumerFile, consumer2.getValidateConsumerArray());
                        consumerFile = "Consumer3-" + delta + " msec@" + getTime();
                        printToFile(consumerFile, consumer3.getValidateConsumerArray());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        public static void printToFile(String outputFileName,Queue<Integer> requestQueue) throws IOException{
                outputFileName = outputFileName.replace(':', '-');
                String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();
                File directory = new File("Practice Coding\\src\\ClockGranularity Test results\\Semaphore and Queue\\");
                File file = File.createTempFile(outputFileName, ".txt",directory);
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
                writer.append("Index \tQueue Contents" + lineSeparator);
                int size = requestQueue.size();
                String summary = "queue<>" + size;
                for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
                        String temp = i + " ticks  \t" + requestQueue.poll();
                        System.out.println(temp);
                        writer.append(temp + lineSeparator);
                }
                writer.append(lineSeparator + "Summary: " + lineSeparator);
                writer.append(summary + lineSeparator);
                System.out.println(outputFileName + " " + summary);
                writer.close();
        }
}
class Buffer {
        private Queue<Integer> requestsQueue;
        Semaphore accessQueue;
        Buffer() {
                requestsQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                accessQueue = new Semaphore(1);
        }
        public void put(Integer tick) throws InterruptedException {
                accessQueue.acquire();
                requestsQueue.add(tick);
                accessQueue.release();
        }
        public synchronized int get() throws InterruptedException {
                int tick;
                while(requestsQueue.size() == 0) {
                        try {
                                wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
                accessQueue.acquire();
                tick = requestsQueue.poll();
                accessQueue.release();
                return tick;
        }
        public Queue<Integer> getQueue() {
                return requestsQueue;
        }
}

class Consumer extends Thread{
        private Buffer bufferQueue;
        private Queue<Integer> validateConsumer;
        Consumer(Buffer requestQueue) {
                bufferQueue = requestQueue;
                validateConsumer = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        }
        public void run() {
                while(true) {
                        int i;
                        try {
                                i = bufferQueue.get();
                                validateConsumer.add(i);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
        }
        public Queue<Integer> getValidateConsumerArray() {
                return validateConsumer;
        }
}

class Producer extends Thread{
        public int tick = 0;
        private Buffer bufferQueue;
        Producer(Buffer requestQueue) {
                bufferQueue = requestQueue;    
        }
        public void run() {
                try {
                        bufferQueue.put(tick++);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Replace Buffer with ConcurrentLinkedQueue and you're done. Not sure why this got locked, this is a very simple issue with a single answer.

Comment: I understand that there maybe many possible answers. I am willing to try them all. I am fairly new to threads and am having a difficult time understanding what am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Buffer` implementation is wrong. It essentially serializes read/writes thus terrible performance. You need to use or implement a [reader-writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) instead.

Comment: He has reinvented the ConcurrentLinkedQueue in a bad way. The correct answer would be: use ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Answer (score 1):

Things you can do:

-Instead of doing busy loops (the query for time may be reducing your utilization), see if there is a difference if you put the producer code code to while(true) like you do with the consumers, sleep the main thread for MaxExecutionTimeMsec time, and do an interrupt on the producer like you do a consumer.

-This is backwards from its typically usage but run a *special* profiler and see how much time is spent where. If it isn't a business section (say waiting for lock acquisition) do a redesign there.

-You may want to look into spin-locks if performance is key and you have a multi-core p
processor. A context switch can be more expensive than a spin-lock in some amortized scenarios.